# Wronskian of complex second order linear differential equation

Tags: complex-numbers, differential-equations, dissipation

While studying certain analogue gravity models I came across a differential equation of the form:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} + \omega^2 (z)~ y(z) = 0
\end{align}
where $z$ is a complex variable and $\omega(z), y(z)$ are functions of the complex variable $z$.

- Am I right in saying that this equation models a dissipative system whenever $Im(\omega) \neq 0$ ?

Secondly, if the above equation contained only real variables and their real valued functions, we could have defined a Wronskian.

- Can I construct a Wronskian similarly here?

If yes, then that Wronskian should be a constant function of $z$, like a 'conserved quantity'.

- Does this contradict with the fact that the above differential equation is dissipative?

Comment: Wronskians in the complex domain are encountered in http://dlmf.nist.gov/ in particular in http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.13 The situation can be different from the real case, see people.cs.uchicago.edu/~lebovitz/Eodesbook/an.pdf In the real case $Imω≠0$ in general implies dissipativity. How do you define dissipativity here?

Comment: I had asked the same question on maths SE and the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1612152/171773  defines dissipativity in this context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.